# Are these buttons round, or nodular?

Tags: ios, button, rounded-corners

Maybe my eyes are deceiving me, but after using this code to create round buttons for a number pad similar to iPhone's Phone app:

```
        for subStack in (mainStackView?.arrangedSubviews)! {

            for thisView in (subStack.subviews) {

                if let button = thisView as? UIButton {


                    button.layer.borderWidth = 2
                    button.layer.borderColor = orangeBorderColor

                    button.frame.size.width = 76
                    button.frame.size.height = 76
                    button.layer.cornerRadius = 0.5 * (button.bounds.size.height)
                    button.layer.masksToBounds = true
//                    button.clipsToBounds = true
                    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
                    button.titleLabel?.font = button.titleLabel?.font.withSize(30)
                    button.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
                }
            }
        }
```

I get things that look like this:

[image]

I've tried using `clipsToBounds`, `maskToBounds`, I've tried the button's `.frame` and its `.bounds` property as the basis for the arithmetic, but they still look nodular rather than round to me.

Can someone please offer a suggestion for smoothing them out?

Thanks!

**Edit**

When I add this:

```
                print(button.frame.size as Any)
                print(button.bounds.size as Any)
                print(button.layer.cornerRadius as Any)
```

I get this in the console:

```
(76.0, 76.0)
(76.0, 76.0)
38.0
```

Comment: an you show the rest of your code?

Comment: That’s all there is. I added the buttons in Storyboard, and used this code to modify the shape. I adapted the code from an old Objective-C project, and the original code produced perfect circles. Can you tell me which code you’re interested in?

Comment: OK what do you get when you print the frame?

Comment: Let me check...

Comment: Please see edit above for the frame and bounds size...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't directly set the frames of views that are laid out using constraints, and arranged subviews of a stack view must be laid out using constraints. That's your problem. Auto layout is (later) overriding your attempt to set the frame, so your corner radius doesn't match the size of your buttons.

Make a subclass of `UIButton`. In your subclass, override `layoutSubviews` to set the button's `cornerRadius` (and don't forget to call `super.layoutSubviews`).

Comment: I had a sneaking suspicion that it might have something to do with Stack views. I'll implement your answer and I'm sure it'll fix the problem. Since I'm pretty new to Swift (and a pretty slow programmer), it'll take me a little time, but I'll report back. Thanks!